# Default return value for a template variable

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a template link list implementation in which

```
T List<T>::GetElementFromHead()
```

returns value from the head of the list. What value should be returned when the list is empty.

```
template <class T>
T List<T>::GetElementFromHead()
{
    T element;
    if (!IsEmpty())
    {
        element = Head->value;
    }
    return element;
}
```

If `IsEmpty()` returns *true* then `return element;` throws exception.

How do I return null or and empty value in this case?

Comment: If `IsEmpty()` is true the element throws an exception because you are trying to return a declared but uninitialized variable.

Comment: In general, you don't. Throwing an exception sounds good to me.

Comment: Make sure that types used as the template parameter T have valid default and copy constructors

Comment: @EliSadoff, you are correct, but is there a default value that can be set?

Comment: @user3159253 this can/will be used for any datatype. including int, strings and custom data types.

Comment: int, std::string and other "standard" types do have valid default and copy constructors. For integral types default value is 0, for std::string — an empty string and they don't produce an exception on copying, obviously. What kind of exception do you get?

Comment: @user3159253 how do I set a generic default value to `element`.
Is there something like. `T element = T.Default();` that I can do?

Comment: @user3159253, The exception I am getting is returning an uninitialized variable.

Comment: You do invoke default T constructor in the statement `T element`. If T is a primitive (integral) type you may get a _compiler warning_ about uninitialized variable, not a runtime exception. If you get an exception, then a class for which you instantiate your `List` generates this exception.

Comment: In C++11 you may avoid `-Wuninitialized` warning by using `T element{};` which essentially is the excplicit way to invoke type default constructor. But again, it's just a workaround against compiler warning, not an exception

Comment: @user3159253, `T element{}` worked. Thanks much:). You are right, it was not an exception but a run time warning.

Comment: @codeAndQuote: compile time warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What value should be returned when the list is empty.

There are two reasonable options.

1. Who cares. Set as a precondition that `GetElementFromHead()` shall only be called if the list isn't empty, and then you can just write:

   ```
   template <class T>
   T& List<T>::GetElementFromHead() {
       return Head->value;
   }
   ```

   This has several nice things about it. No copies. It's fast. I can modify the value if I want to. No extra branch, since you're requiring the user to do it up front. No need to worry about what the error case is or coming up with a reasonable sentinel value. If you return `T{}`, what if `T` is `int` and the list can have `0` normally - how does the user differentiate between a "real" `0` and a "fake" `0`?

   This is how the standard library implements [`list::front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/front), [`vector::front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front), etc. Do as the standard library do is usually a good decision.
2. Encapsulate in the return value itself whether or not it's a real value:

   ```
   template <class T>
   std::optional<T> List<T>::GetElementFromHead() {
       if (!IsEmpty()) {
           return Head->value;
       }
       else {
           return std::nullopt;
       }
   }
   ```

   (If using `boost::optional`, the last line should return `boost::none`). This way, the return value itself makes it clear what situation we're in - we either have a value and that value is the front of the list, or we don't have a value. Again, no need to come up with a sentinel.

   An alternative version of this would be to return a `T*`, and `nullptr` on failure. This has the advantage that it doesn't incur a copy or require that `T` be copy constructible.